# Powershell script for copying and logging

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have search for similar answers to this and still I am going round in a circle(s).

I am new to any form of scripting so this is a bastardised script. The script is basically copying log files and data from locations to a remote server and making an append log each time it does it but for the life in me I cant get it to work over the network only local, by changing the `$dirname = "D:\${env:computername}"`.

I would appreciate any feed back and help. This came about from a batch file I created and thought to try and progress in the dark arts.

The script is going to be scheduled to run task when a machines connects to the network.

thanks in advance

**update**

I get no output or error message from the log file at all no txt or data of any type, As for error messages I am trying to copy from local to server in a vm scenario and will not run, but if I apply this on the local machine it will copy c to d no problem. as I said complete novice

```
missing function body in function declaration
at line:2 char1
<<<<c:script\copy_log.ps1
+categoryinfo    : parser error: (:) []. ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingFunctionBody
```

Apologies for format had to type it as I can c+p from the unit

**UPDATE**

figured out that the share to the other server was not shared correctly fixed this but the script still does not create a log file

```
function CopyLogFiles ($sourcePackage) { #used this syntax as I couldn't get anything else to work and took it from here
    $dirName = "\\server\$sourcePackage" #server it is going to
    if (!(Test-Path $dirName)) { mkdir $dirName }
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\ESS-T\$sourcePackage\Logs" -Destination $dirName -Recurse -Force
}

CopyLogFiles AppLauncher_V2.0.0.7
CopyLogFiles MMA_V2.0.0.12
CopyLogFiles MML_V2.0.0.4
CopyLogFiles SerialDataReader_V2.0.0.5 

function Log-Write {
    Param ([string]$LogString)
    Add-Content $LogFile -value $LogString
}

$LogFile = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ESS-T\.log"
```

Comment: Hi, can you please edit your question and include the error message you get when using a remote location ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. `Copy-Item` is convenient for small cases, but Windows has had `robocopy` included with every install since Windows 7 and it's faster, more robust, **and has logging built in** with the `/log:FILENAME` switch.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx

Go ahead and test for the existence of your destination & create it manually in your PowerShell script, but leave the logging of the copy operation to `robocopy`.

Edit: You aren't creating the logfile because you don't define the logfile name until **after** the rest of your code runs.

Comment: Hi thanks for the replay, I had the robocopy one working as a bat fine that's what got me thinking (if you knew me you would know that's bad) about trying to use powershell to do similar things   luckily for me I think I will end up using the batch file but just wanted to know how logging works ,

Comment: You can still use PowerShell - just use it to wrap Robocopy.